# How to dismiss progress Bar

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I'm using progressDialog for my fragment inside Bindviewholder where it loads untill the images and text are not  filled from online. But  I want my progress Dialog to dismiss or hide once it is all loaded but I did place my Progress Dialog below

```
 youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
```

But still progress dialog is not released and it is visible. 
How can I hide progress dialog . Please Help

Below is my code

```html
public class YoutubeVideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YoutubeViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = YoutubeVideoAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<YoutubeVideoModel> youtubeVideoModelArrayList;




    public YoutubeVideoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<YoutubeVideoModel> youtubeVideoModelArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.youtubeVideoModelArrayList = youtubeVideoModelArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public YoutubeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_video_custom_layout, parent, false);
        return new YoutubeViewHolder(view);



    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(YoutubeViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait..."); // Setting Message
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading"); // Setting Title
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); // Progress Dialog Style Spinner
        progressDialog.show(); // Display Progress Dialog
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        final YoutubeVideoModel youtubeVideoModel = youtubeVideoModelArrayList.get(position);

        holder.videoTitle.setText(youtubeVideoModel.getTitle());
        holder.videoDuration.setText(youtubeVideoModel.getDuration());


        /*  initialize the thumbnail image view , we need to pass Developer Key */
        holder.videoThumbnailImageView.initialize(Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, final YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
                //when initialization is sucess, set the video id to thumbnail to load

                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(youtubeVideoModel.getVideoId());

                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                        //when thumbnail loaded successfully release the thumbnail loader as we are showing thumbnail in adapter
                        youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
                        //print or show error when thumbnail load failed
                        Log.e(TAG, "Youtube Thumbnail Error");
                    }
                });
               
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                //print or show error when initialization failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Youtube Initialization Failure");

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return youtubeVideoModelArrayList != null ? youtubeVideoModelArrayList.size() : 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to set the visibility of progressbar as below answer. I am not sure of youTubeThumbnailLoader.release() in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states that you are using progress bar but your code contains progress dialog , both of them are different.To dismiss the progress dialog you need to call the dismiss method as

`progressDialog.dismiss();`

Comment: sorry I just edited it..it was progressDialog. please check.